# Странная ошибка

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]код mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private Button button;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
//myzika
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openActivity2();
            }
        });
    }
   public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, media_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
                                  }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

подчеркивается

```
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}
```

стандартные решение проблем в андроид студио не помогло

я хотел создать онклик на кнопку для перехода на другой активити

word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word

logcat:

```
2020-06-11 18:05:35.770 4813-4813/com.example.easyclass4 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.easyclass4, PID: 4813
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.easyclass4/com.example.easyclass4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.easyclass4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: а ошибку показать можете? так сложно помочь чем-то

Comment: да, добавил скрин

Comment: пожалуйста, не надо удалять содержимое вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в этом куске кода:

```
 public void openActivity2() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, media_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
                                  }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
```

странная и непонятная мне скобка `}` посередине. Если это не ошибка при копировании, то вероятнее всего студия просто не понимает что за код снаружи метода и внутри класса. Уберите скобку и должно все нормально быть по логике. Вообще вот есть [подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147039/how-to-use-appbarconfiguration-and-setnavigationitemselectedlistener-together) где используется практически полностью ваш код и там все работает правильно :)

**P.S.** Не нужно создавать глобальную переменную `mAppBarConfiguration`  которая используется только в одном месте, просто объявите ее внутри метода:

```
AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
```

Comment: боже спаси и сохрани вас)

Comment: но теперь приложение просто вылетает

Comment: сейчас логкэт посмотрю

Comment: прикрепил logcat

Comment: однако да, в fragment_gallery

Comment: в activity_main его нету.

Comment: нужно чтобы был, вы ведь на кнопку какую-то нажимать хотите? добавьте кнопку если ее нет и присвойте ей id

Comment: кнопка в fragment_galery находится imageButton3, в fragment_home (под activity_main) присвоил id для одной из кнопок там, сути не меняет, или я вас неправильно понял?

Comment: activity_main - это что за макет?

Comment: макет activity_main. Он по умолчанию. В жизни там ничего не менял, только шторку проверял

Comment: так, давайте я вам опишу что вы пытаетесь сделать, а вы уже сами решите как это исправлять, так как я не вижу структуру и наполнение вашего проекта и мне сложно точно указать где что поменять. У вас есть код который вы представили в вопросе, в этом коде вы используете activity_main.xml, данный код использует кнопку которая находится на другом макете, и при попытке ее (кнопку) использовать, приложение как это и должно быть падает. Почему - потому что в том макете который использует ваша активность в вопросе, нету кнопки которую вы пытаетесь вызвать, переместите кнопку в xml активности :)

Comment: тоесть то что я прописал в MainActivity я вписал не туда. Ошибку я понял, спасибо. Мне это надо было вписать в другой активити

Comment: вам нужно упорядочить ваш код, чтобы активность использовала виджеты которые есть в ее xml и не пыталась вызывать то чего у нее нету)